# Animate CC 2017.1: Test in browser on Google Chrome says "Get Adobe Flash Player" even though it's enabled?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, browser, animate-cc

Tried to be specific in the title, but it's difficult, sorry. Anyways, I'm trying to test something in Adobe Animate CC 2017.1 in my browser, but no matter what I do it always says "Get Adobe Flash Player" with the download button. I already downloaded it and I have it allowed for this "website" even though it's just file:///Users/*******/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/Untitled-1.html
I'm on Google Chrome on Mac OS X El Capitan [my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwCpE.png)

Comment: Testing from local disk is the worst thing you can do to Flash. Click on icon with **(i)** left from the URL and change **Flash** setting from **Always Ask** to **Allow**.

Comment: @Organis I know I'm late, but I already did this and I'm still having this problem. Didn't do a thing sorry

Comment: Ugh. Try different HTML embedding techniques. At least one with direct **object** and **embed** tags and one via **swfobject** library. If it still won't work, then it might be some Mac OS thing and you should test it online, not locally.